# How to prove the equality of the following two infinite summations?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I found this problem in the book Analysis 1 by Otto Forster (Problem 8.3), the book is in german, so I will restate the problem in english, it is to prove that the following statement is true: For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x|<1$ we have the following equality:

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n^2} \right)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n}A(n) $$

with the function $$A(n)=|\{ (k,l)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\mid n=k^2+l^2 \}|$$I tried to prove this statement using the formula of Cauchy for product of two infinite series, but to no avail. I still don't  get the idea how to tie down $A(n)$ with the $x$. For example, by Cauchy:

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n^2}\right)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k^2}x^{(n-k)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k^2-n}x^{(n-k)^2}$$

Now what's left to to is to show that

$(2)$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k^2-n}x^{(n-k)^2}= A(n)$$

But I don't think this is the case, since if we were to plug in $n=3$,
we would get the result of the LHS being unequal to zero whereas the RHS equals zero, so this shows that although the statement holds, (2) does not necessarily be true, so I wonder if there is another approach to this problem starting from the construction of $A(n)$ itself. I tried to construct it but didn't see the connection of $A(n)$ and $x$, since for example,

$$A(n)=\sum_{0 \leq k,l\leq n} [n=k^2+l^2]=\sum_{0 \leq k\leq n} \left(\left \lfloor{\sqrt{n-k^2}}\right \rfloor-\left \lceil{\sqrt{n-k^2}}\right \rceil +1 \right)=\sum_{0 \leq k\leq n} \left \lfloor\frac{\left \lfloor n-k^2 \right \rfloor}{n-k^2}\right \rfloor $$

But still there isn't any $x$ involved. I would really appreciate it if you can give me a clue before the proper answer. Thanks!

Comment: What does $\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n^2} = 1\right)^2$ mean? I don't think the $= 1$ should be there.

Comment: @JairTaylor sorry it was my mistake

Comment: @JairTaylor I think what you mean and what I used are different, I used "Cauchy product of two infinite series" whereas what you mean is "Cauchy product of two power series", as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product . Are they not essentially the same?

Comment: Ah, I see now, I think you're right.

Comment: The problem though is that the inner sum you got $\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k^2}x^{(n-k)^2}$ does not correspond to a single monomial $x^n$ and so isn't very helpful if you want to figure out the coefficient of $x^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cauchy product is $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i \right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i x^i \right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^n a_i b_{n-i} x^n.$$

In the case of $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2} \right)^2,$$ we take $a_i = b_i = 1$ if $i$ is a perfect square, otherwise $a_i=b_i=0$.  So

$$a_i b_{n-i} = 1$$ if both $i$ and $n-i$ are perfect squares, otherwise $0$.  Therefore $$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i b_{n-i} = \cdots$$

Edit: Or more directly,
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2}\right)^2 &= \left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{i^2}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{j^2}\right) \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{i^2+j^2} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{0 \leq i,j < \infty, i^2 +j^2 = n} x^{i^2+j^2}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \sum_{0 \leq i,j < \infty, i^2 +j^2 = n} 1\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate, I don't get why we are allowed to set $a_i$ and also $b_i$ as we like, wasn't it set to be 1 by the problem? $1* x^{n^2}$

Comment: Here $a_i$ is the coefficient of $x^i$ in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2} = 1 + x + x^4 + x^9 + \cdots = 1 + 1x + 0x^2 + 0x^3 + 1x^4 + 0x^5 + \cdots$ which is $1$ if $i$ is a perfect square, otherwise $0$.

Comment: I see what you did there! So you changed  $n^2$ to $n$, but is there any motivation behind this move?

Comment: It's just that it's easier to think in terms of sums $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i$ (since they is how we usually index power series, e.g. for the Cauchy product) instead of sums that look like $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^{n^2}$.  So we reindex so that the $i$th term corresponds to the coefficient of $x^i$.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!